# Creating an ITK displacement field image from a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, itk

In my PhD project I analyze 3D microCT datasets of lung tissue samples. One topic is the simulation of an atelectasis by warping the image using ITK Python. In order to achieve that (with the WarpImageFilter or the ResampleImageFilter in ITK) I have to create a displacement vector field. Therefore, I have to convert a 3D numpy array into an itk image using the GetImageFromArray function. The resulting output should be in a format which the ResampleImageFilter or WarpImageFilter can work with:

Here´s my code:

```
array1 = []

for i in range (-5,5):
    for j in range(-5,5):
        for k in range(-5,5):
            if i == 0 and j == 0 and k == 0:
                array1.append([0, 0, 0])
            else:
                x = (float(i)/float(i**2 + j**2 + k**2))
                y = (float(j)/float(i**2 + j**2 + k**2))
                z = (float(k)/float(i**2 + j**2 + k**2))
                array1.append([x, y, z])


displacementFieldFileName = itk.image_from_array(np.reshape(array1, (10,10,10,3)), is_vector = True)
```

The last line shows the conversion from a numpy array into a 3D ITK vector image format which is needed by the filters mentioned above. However, I receive the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File “Test_Displacement.py”, line 39, in
displacementFieldFileName = itk.image_from_array(np.reshape(array1, (10,10,10,3)), is_vector = True)
File “/XXXX/YYYY/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/itkExtras.py”, line 297, in GetImageFromArray
return _GetImageFromArray(arr, “GetImageFromArray”, is_vector)
File “/XXXX/YYYY/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/itkExtras.py”, line 291, in _GetImageFromArray
templatedFunction = getattr(itk.PyBuffer[ImageType], function)
File “/XXXX/YYYY/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/itkTemplate.py”, line 340, in getitem
raise TemplateTypeError(self, tuple(cleanParameters))
itkTemplate.TemplateTypeError: itk.PyBuffer is not wrapped for input type itk.Image[itk.Vector[itk.D,3],3].
```

A similar topic can be found here:
https://discourse.itk.org/t/importing-image-from-array-and-axis-reorder/1192

I already tried using `dtype=np.float32` and `.astype(np.float32)` to specify the float data type but this leads to another error:

```
File "Test_Displacement.py", line 59, in <module>
    fieldReader.SetFileName(displacementFieldFileName)
TypeError: in method 'itkImageFileReaderIF3_SetFileName', argument 2 of type 'std::string const &'
```

How can the displacement field created properly? Any help will be highly appreciated!
Alex

Comment: It looks like the float32 version is working ok. itk.image_from_array is returning an itk image.  What type is your fieldReader?  I'm guessing SetFileName is expecting a string, not an itk image.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it's asking for:

```py
itk.Image[itk.Vector[itk.D,3],3]
```

Not a numpy array. Or maybe your numpy array has the wrong dimensionality.